# How do I show the menu bar?

Tags: raspbian, settings

I just got my Pi 2 and started experimenting on it.

I'm running Raspbian and I installed xrdp for remote desktop.
I created a new user "prograde", and logged via rdp, and it works fine. The problem is, that I don't get the bar at the top, and no menu button. It's just a clean desktop and a waste basket.

If I log in with the pi account, the top bar and the menu button are there.

Where do I find the settings to show or not show them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common problem for this is that the `.xsession` file is missing from the new user's home directory. Try copying that file from the pi user's home directory to that of the new user.

**Edit:**

As prograde mentioned in the comments, it appears some versions have moved the file to `.config/.lxsession`

Comment: I found no .xseesion in the home directory, but there was a .config/.lxsession directory that i copied, and when I logged in again, I had a menu bar. So thanks! =)

Comment: @prograde: sounds like a setting file changed between versions... Glad it helped! :)

Comment: The next time I logged in, the menu panel had dissappeared... Is there a spec for the config somewhere, so that I can edit the settings for the desktop?